# Apache and linux file permissions can't browse file or directories

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, magento, administration

I just copied my magento site over to a local server running CentOS 5.4. The browser said it can't locate the location of the stylesheets. The stylesheets are within /skin/frontend/my_new_interface/design2/css. I tried to view in the browser and I can't view any of the files within the css directory. I verified a million times that I'm typing in the correct location. I can view files within /skin/frontend/my_new_interface/design2. Can't browse directories within browser however.

I typed in ls -l css

and get:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache
```

listed for all the files

I tried chmod -R 755 and the directories

I changed the apache conf Options Indexes

But still when I browse the directories I get Forbidden.  However, in another fresh installation of magento in the same www dir, I am able to browse directories. As far as I can tell both installations have same ownership and permissions.

I also tried

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

which was recommended in the magento wiki

I've just run out of ideas.

Comment: Idea: check the Apache log files. Turn on more verbose logging if necessary.

Comment: I guess I need to turn the error logs on first :)

Comment: nevermind. I found them.

Comment: Error log says Directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: Apache isn't letting you browse directories because it's disabled then. As for files, are you sure that apache is the apache user on your install?

Comment: What happens you try to access the CSS files directly.  "Directory index forbidden by Options directive " means your web server isn't configured to show a list of files when you view a directory.

Comment: I put a test.css file in the css dir and also one in css's parent directory. I can view test.css in the parent directory only, not the one within the css directory.

Comment: okay this makes no sense to me

within design2 dir

I removed css directory, then made new css directory, then copied over the contents. Still didn't work.

Then I created a test directory within design2 and copied the contents over. That worked.

All along I deleted my browser cache with each trial and even magento's var/cache.

Comment: I think I should move this question in server fault instead. Sorry I'm new.

Comment: Well i just figured out it was a rewrite rule within htaccess. I don't quite understand the rewrite rule, but commenting it out fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file permission were set up correctly. I figured out that the .htaccess had a rewrite rule set for the css directory that was causing the problem. I inherited this site and am still not aware of all the little modifications done throughout.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add `Options +Indexes` to your `httpd.conf` or in a `.htaccess` file in the `css/` folder to view the folder contents through the browser.  This is bad ju-ju though.  Do you really need to switch this on, or can you keep doing it through the ssh session?

On the CSS file note, can you type `pwd` when in the CSS directory?  That'll help us confirm you've got the correct location.  Do you get "Forbidden" when you try to view the CSS file directory, or just when you try to view the directory contents?